# Winforms - Open external pdf file

Tags: winforms, pdf

I've Googled and searched stackoverflow for this but I've not found an answer that is suitable.

All I want to do is place a button a form, the code behind this button will contain a reference to a location on a harddrive where a pdf file is stored. All I want to do is have it so that when the user clicks the button the pdf file opens in the machines selected pdf reader (this is an internal application so the 2-3 machines that access it will always have adobe acrobat on them).

I've no idea which (if any) of the built in .NET classes can do this.

**EDIT: There will be 100's of pdfs all added throughout time, I will have a path reference to one pdf per order in my system which points to a file storage server where the PDF lies. The PDF is not locally hosted.**

How can this be done in the simplest sense?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfPath)` will open the file in the default program. It works on local files and UNC paths.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use this code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\myPdf.pdf");
```

It will open the file you provide with its associated default program

Comment: Thanks to you and Andrew Barber (who did effectively answer first albeit in the comments).

Comment: That didn't work well. This is better

                                    var p = new Process();
                                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(tmpFile)
                                    {
                                        UseShellExecute = true
                                    };
                                    p.Start();